# diseño bootstrap en tabla PHP

Tags: css, bootstrap

estoy construyendo una tabla en PHP y me gustaría darle diseño Bootstrap,la tabla funciona bien pero quiero trabajar en el diseño si me pueden colaborar indicándome donde puedo colocar el `<table id="tablaID" class="table table-hover">`

```
            <!-- Tabla -->
        <div class="units-row">

            <!-- Resumen SOLICITADAS-->
            <div class="unit-100">

                <!-- Titulo -->
                <div id="titulos" class="units-row">
                    <div class="unit-100"><h1 class="titulo_contenedor">TRASLADOS</h1></div>
                </div>

                <table id="tablaID" class="table table-hover">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th width="0px">N° Orden</th>
                            <th>Siniestro</th>
                            <th>Nombre y Apellido</th>
                            <th>Fecha</th>
                            <th width="90px"></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>                        
                    <tbody>
  <?php 
         $link = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", ""); 
         mysql_select_db("helpdesk", $link); 
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT id_solicitud, orden, nombre_apellido, status, fecha, desde, provincia FROM traslados", $link); 
        if ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    { 
        do 
        { 
         echo "<tr>
             <td>".$row["id_solicitud"]."</td>
             <td>".$row["orden"]."</td>
             <td>".$row["nombre_apellido"]."</td>
             <td>".$row["status"]."</td>
             <td>".$row["fecha"]."</td>
         </tr> \n"; 
        } 
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)); 
     echo "</table> \n"; 
    }   
        else 
        { 
    echo "¡ No se ha encontrado ningún registro !"; 
       } 
?> 

                            </tr>


                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

Comment: no es buena practica usar mucha etiqueta html dentro de codigo php a la vez, ademas aburre poner tanto echo, pero bueno, asi como pusiste tu html basico para crear un tabla asi mismo crea etiquetas dentro de los echo para crear los links de las librerias de bootstrap o cdn's echo "<link href="ruta_de_los_archivos/bootstrap.min.css"> y asi con lo demas. Espero te funcione.

Comment: Ya intentaste hacerlo directo? 
echo '<table id="tablaID" class="table table-hover">'; en ves de echo "<table border = '2'> \n";

Comment: Ya lo solucione. Arriba dejo el código.

Comment: que version  de bootstrap estas usando, que tienes en en tablaID